# javascript promise readfile

Tags: javascript, promise

I have two file readers, and two Promises as well, one for each file reader as you can see below.

```
var fs1 = require('fs');
var fs2 = require('fs');
var r = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs1.readFile('reads.txt','utf8',function(e,d){
        if(e) reject('E R')
        else resolve(d.trim());
    })
});
var w = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs2.readFile('write.txt','utf8',function(e,d){
        if(e) reject('E W')
        else resolve(d.trim());
    })
});


Promise.all([r,w])
    .then(function(q) {
        console.log(q);
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    })
```

This works fine, but I like to have the reading file section to be in a separate function, something like this:

```
function filereader( theFS, theFilePath){
....
}
```

Is it possible, and how?
Thanks

Comment: You mean a function that starts from fs1 and fs2 so you don't repeat code?

Comment: Yes of course it is, please try. It's no different than abstracting any other code into a function.

Comment: Notice that `fs1 === fs2`. There's only one module, requiring `fs` multiple times doesn't change that.

Comment: @AmirShahbabaie Where are you using the function parameters like `theFilePath` in there? What do you `return`?

Comment: Just as a hint, since NodeJS 8 there is [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to convert the callback-based functions to promise-based.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't just write a function for it?

```
var fs1 = require('fs');
var fs2 = require('fs');

function filereader(fsRef, path) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fsRef.readFile(path,'utf8',function(e,d){
        if(e) reject('E R')
        else resolve(d.trim());
    })
  })
}

var w = filereader(fs2, 'write.txt')

var r = filereader(fs1, 'read.txt')

Promise.all([r,w])
    .then(function(q) {
        console.log(q);
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    })
```

Comment: No, there's no reason, it seems to be the question *how* to do that.

Comment: You should use the function for `w` as well.